# How to ingest inline into Azure Data Explorer Table from PowerShell?

Tags: .net, azure, powershell, kql, azure-data-explorer

Inline ingestion into an [Azure Data Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/data-explorer-overview) Table is possible through the [`.ingest inline` control command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-ingestion/ingest-inline):

```
.ingest inline into table MyTable with (format = 'csv') <|
    "this","inline","CSV","gets","ingested","to","MyTable"
```

This self-answer provides guidance on how to ingest inline from PowerShell using the [`Kusto.Data` assembly from `Kusto.Tools` package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Kusto.Tools/).

Usage of the assembly is partially documented in [**Use Kusto .NET client libraries from PowerShell**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/powershell/powershell?tabs=user), however it does not cover inline ingestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer covers inline ingestion with CSV format, however do note, several formats are supported for this, see [**Data formats supported by Azure Data Explorer for ingestion**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingestion-supported-formats) for details.

Worth noting that the service principal used for ingestion will require at least [Table Ingestor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/access-control/role-based-access-control):

```
.add table MyTable ingestors (
    'aadapp=xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx;myTenant.xyz')
```

---

Below example is compatible with PowerShell 7+ (net6.0 assembly), for Windows PowerShell 5.1, use net472 assembly.

```bash
# Nuget Package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Kusto.Tools/

# - net472 = PowerShell 5.1
# - net6.0 = PowerShell 7+
$assembly = Convert-Path .\microsoft.azure.kusto.tools.12.0.1\tools\net6.0\Kusto.Data.dll

try {
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($assembly)

    # NOTE: `Select-Object -Skip 1` is only needed if the CSV has headers,
    #       headers must be skipped for Csv ingestion.
    $data = [System.IO.File]::ReadLines('path\to\csvToIngest.csv') |
        Select-Object -Skip 1

    $clusterUrl = 'https://mySourceCluster.eastus.kusto.windows.net'
    $databaseName = 'myDb'
    $tableName = 'myTable'
    $tenantId = 'xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx'

    # Do yourself a favor and use a Key Vault for this part :(
    $adxClientId = 'xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx'
    $adxSecret = 's3cr3t'

    $queryProvider = [Kusto.Data.Net.Client.KustoClientFactory]::CreateCslQueryProvider(
        [Kusto.Data.KustoConnectionStringBuilder]::new($clusterUrl, $databaseName).
            WithAadApplicationKeyAuthentication($adxClientId, $adxSecret, $tenantId))

    $crp = [Kusto.Data.Common.ClientRequestProperties]::new()
    $crp.SetOption(
        [Kusto.Data.Common.ClientRequestProperties]::OptionServerTimeout,
        [TimeSpan]::FromSeconds(30))

    $null = $queryProvider.ExecuteControlCommand(
        [string]::Format(
            ".ingest inline into table {0} with (format = 'csv') <| {1}",
            $tableName, [string]::Join([Environment]::NewLine, $data)), $crp)
}
finally {
    ${queryProvider}?.Dispose()
}
```