Authenticate to Kusto in a powershell loop
I am working on a PowerShell script which gets data from the file system and then for information found in each file runs a Kusto query to find information about that entity.
Each time it runs the Kusto query it authenticates which does not scale. I need to authenticate once.
Below is a sample of the code


[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("D:\microsoft.azure.kusto.tools.12.1.1\tools\net472\Kusto.Data.dll")

$clusterUrl = "<my URL here>"
$databaseName = "<databaseName>"

$queryProvider = [Kusto.Data.Net.Client.KustoClientFactory]::CreateCslQueryProvider(
    [Kusto.Data.KustoConnectionStringBuilder]::new($clusterUrl, $databaseName).
        WithAadUserPromptAuthentication("microsoft.com"))

$array = "A", "B"

foreach ($item in $array)
{

  $query = "WorkflowRunHistory | where Status != `"Succeeded`" | where WorkflowName == `"$item`" | limit 1  "

    # Run the query
    $reader = $queryProvider.ExecuteQuery($query)

    # Process the result
    $Materialize = [Kusto.Cloud.Platform.Data.ExtendedDataReader]::Materialize($reader)
    if ( $Materialize.HasRows ) { wite-host "$item is good" } 
} # loop for each file


authentication happens after calling WithAadApplicationKeyAuthentication on the CreateCslQueryProvider instance, and happens of course only once. Then that query provider can be used multiple times on different calls. This part is missing in your code so unless you provide valid code and not pseudo code it is not possible to help you.

Thanks are you referring to this line, which is included ?
$queryProvider = [Kusto.Data.Net.Client.KustoClientFactory]::CreateCslQueryProvider($kustoConnSB)

Yeah, it's missing the actual authentication piece, see here for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77951880/15339544 .WithAadApplicationKeyAuthentication(...) is used on that instance to actually authenticate with your cluster

Thanks Santiago, that's closer, now I need to find out how to do it using smart card authentication (Entra ID). Now that I have a starting point maybe I can now figure that part out.

I updated the code above but it still authenticates each time through the loop

I guess this is an issue with smartcard auth, I assume you mention you need to re-authenticate due to the smartcard auth popup ? You should probably try to get access thru a delegated authentication (clientId and key) to overcome this issue. As aside, you could easily overcome your current loop issue but performing a single query using where in (....) in your KQL query and passing all loop items  instead.

Thanks Santiago, I will consider that.
